# Laravel шаблонизатор Blade @section использует старое значение переменной

Tags: php, laravel, blade

В общем есть вьюха posts.blade.php:

```php
{{-- ПОСТЫ --}}
@if(isset($posts))
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        @include(env('THEME').'.content.post-preview',compact('post'))
    @endforeach
@endif

{{-- ПАГИНАЦИЯ --}}
{{$posts->links()}}
```

В цикле вызываеся вьюха для отображения поста `@include(env('THEME').'.content.post-preview',compact('post'))` в которую передается постоянно новое значение `$post`.

Содержимое вьюхи post-preview.blade.php:

```php
@extends(env('THEME').'.content.layouts.post')

@section('title')
    <a href="{{route('showPost',['alias'=>$post->alias])}}" class="mt-4 post_title post_link_title">{{$post->title}}</a>
@endsection

@section('body')
        <p class="card-text">{{$post->description}}</p>
        <a href="{{route('showPost',['alias'=>$post->alias])}}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Читать дальше &rarr;</a>
@endsection

@section('footer')
    <hr>
    <span class="text-muted">
        <span class=""><i class="mr-2 ml-2 far fa-eye"></i>{{$post->views}}<a class="float-right comment_link " href="{{ route('showPost',['alias'=>$post->alias]) }}#disqus_thread"><i class="far mr-2 fa-comment-alt"></i>{{$post->getCommentsCount()}}</a></span>
    </span>
    <hr>
@endsection
```

post-preview расширяет макет post.blade.php:

```php
<!-- Автор, дата публикации -->
@include(env('THEME').'.content.post.header')

@yield('title')
<!-- Tags -->
@include(env('THEME').'.content.post.tags')
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{$post->img}}" alt="">

<div class="card-body p-0">
    @yield('body')
</div>

@yield('footer')
```

В итоге соответствует содержимому для каждого поста:

```
@include(env('THEME').'.content.post.header')
@include(env('THEME').'.content.post.tags')
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{$post->img}}" alt="">
```

А все `@yield('title')` `@yield('body')` `@yield('footer')` выводят данные самого первого значения переменной $post.

В документации не какого решения не нашел. Может у кого есть какие предположения?

P.S удалял собранные вьюхи(view:clear), не помогло.

Comment: вы совсем уж как-то нетрадиционно решили использовать `@section`. почитайте о `@parent`, но скорее всего и это вам не поможет. попробуйте через вложенные `@include` реализовать

Comment: Во-первых, не стоит использовать хелпер `env`, в местах, отличных от конфигурации, т.к. при кеширование конфига будет возвращаться null. Во-вторых, есть директивы `@stack -> @push`